# How to search with SQL in two tables, how to assign table alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a search that is currently working to a piont

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting
INNER JOIN catelogue ON catelogue.`CAT NO.` = tracklisting.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE tracklisting.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
```

This is ovblisy bringing back the records in my tracklisting table that match 'placebo'

Now I want it to search my other table in my Db as well, catelogue.

I have tried to do the code but keep getting this error returned

> 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'catelogue'

this was the code i used:

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting, catelogue
INNER JOIN catelogue ON catelogue.`CAT NO.` = tracklisting.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE tracklisting.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo' OR catelogue.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
```

Unfortunatly these tables cannot be merged into one as the tracklisting relates to the album in the catelogue table.

I believe the catelogue table should be assigned an alias but I tried that and got the same message back. I'm probably doing something stupid.

Also should the join change as there are albums that don't have tracklistings as of yet?

Many Thanks

EDIT:

I have tried this code aswell but to no avail. it works works but doesn't seem to return any records from the catelogue table, only the tracklisting table.

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting t
INNER JOIN catelogue c ON c.`CAT NO.` = t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE t.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
OR c.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
```

I seem to have picked up how the alias works, thanks guys.

Basics of what i want. It must search both tables and if a record is found in the catelogue table it will be displayed as is but if a record is found in the tracklisting it must show the record that it matches with from the catelogue table.

Reason the tracklisting table has an artist column is for various artist albums.

Hope that helps as to what i am trying to get to.

Thanks

OK

AFTER DECIDING THAT A JOIN MAY BE THE PROBLEM HERE IT WAS

INNER JOIN HAD TO BE RIGHT JOIN SO EVERYONES CODE HERE WAS CORRECT EXCEPT FOR THE JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting t
RIGHT JOIN catelogue c ON c.`CAT NO.` = t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE t.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
OR c.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
```

THANKS FOR THE HELP

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same fields, you can try:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM tracklisting
WHERE ARTIST LIKE '%mysearchstring%'
UNION
SELECT field1, field2
FROM catelogue
WHERE ARTIST LIKE '%mysearchstring%'
```

Or if you want the join, try:

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting t
INNER JOIN catelogue c ON c.`CAT NO.` = t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%mysearchstring%' OR c.ARTIST LIKE '%mysearchstring%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're joining "catelogue", don't list it in `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting t
INNER JOIN catelogue c ON c.`CAT NO.` = t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE t.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo' OR c.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
```

Comment: I dropped the catelogue out of the FROM clause but it still only returns the results from the tracklisting table. I'd like it to return results from both